# "gksu" doesn't prompt for the root password

Tags: linux, bash, linux-terminal, terminal-emulator, gksudo

I use this terminal emulator `x-terminal-emulator` and when I run this on a normal non-privileged user

```
~$ gksu /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator
```

an app starts and tells me to choose a password for a new keyring and when I click "Cancel",
the program starts with root privilege without asking for my root password.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set a password for your keyring, or remove your gksu password from the keyring.

When you tell a gnome system to remember a password, it places it on the keyring. the keyring should have a master password that you use to unlock the keyring and access your stored passwords automatically.

When your keyring does not have a password, your passwords are stored in cleartext, and you don't need a password to access them, so gksu just reads it normally.

If you set your keyring master password, you will need to enter it upon each boot, the first time you access a stored password. once done, you will not be able to gksu your terminal without either providing the keyring or account password.

If you remove your account password from the keyring, you will be prompted to enter it when running gksu. Just be sure not to tell it to remember the password.

Comment: how to disable keyring?

Comment: no idea. I offered two options, neither of which is disabling the keyring functionality.